# Error installing postgresql with homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

When I run `brew install postgresql` I get this as an error message:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/admin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/icu4c/02.make:
./formatted_string_builder.h:227:9: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
        U_ASSERT(category <= 0xf),
        ^
../common/uassert.h:35:26: note: expanded from macro 'U_ASSERT'
#   define U_ASSERT(exp) void()
                         ^
./formatted_string_builder.h:240:64: note: in call to 'Field(0, 1)'
constexpr FormattedStringBuilder::Field kGeneralNumericField = {UFIELD_CATEGORY_UNDEFINED, 1};
                                                               ^
3 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT numfmt.d numfmt.o numfmt.ao -o numfmt.ao numfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [numfmt.ao] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

These open issues may also help:
icu4c 67.1 (make C++14 compatible) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/59540

Error: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.
```

I have tried brew update (I am already up to date), and the only issue brew doctor gives me is that there are unexpected header files.

I am using

- OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
- Homebrew 2.4.12

Comment: Look at the 'Error:' portion of the message it tells you why.

Comment: `OSX Yosemite 10.10.5` this is kind of bummer.